# can free() function work in cascade in c

Tags: c

Suppose I have this code

```
struct card
{
    int val;
    char* type; 
    struct card* next;
};

struct card* new_card;
new_card = (struct card*) malloc(sizeof(struct card));

//some initialization of new_card

free(new_card);
```

My question is - Now when I free new_card, do type and next pointers in card also free their memories in cascade with this command?
Or do I have to first free type and next pointers, then free new_card?

Answer (score 2):

No. You need to manually `free` the card pointed to by `new_card->next` before you free `new_card`, and so on, if you want to free the whole lot. One `free()` for each `malloc()`.

Comment: I have another question. If I have two pointers and I allot space dynamically through one of them, can I equate the second pointer to the first one? just by ptr2 = ptr1; ? and then ptr2 will also point to place where ptr1 does?

Comment: Yes, in which case you also only need `free()` once. One `free()` per `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the case. If `type` and `next` point to some dynamically allocated memory (with `malloc`, for example), you need to `free` them before deleting `new_card`.

If not, just `free( new_card );` is fine.